# Writing an implementation of Selection Sort in Python and my code is throwing "min() arg is an empty set" on a populated list

Tags: python, sorting

As an exercise, I am writing an implementation of selection sort (as well as insertion sort and quick sort); for me, the best way to gain a deeper understanding of a function is implementing it myself. I have the following code:

```
def selectionSort(L):
    S = []
    i = 0
    a = len(L)
    while i <= a:
        S.append(min(L)) #Find min(L) and add it to set S
        L.remove(min(L)) #Remove that same element min(L) from L
        i += 1
    return S #Return the sorted list
L = [int(x) for x in input('Input a list to be sorted: ').split()]
print(selectionSort(L))
```

The idea here is to have the user input a list of integers to be sorted and run the `selectionSort()` function on the list. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why `min(L)` is throwing the error `min() arg is an empty sequence`. I have written other code which takes a list as input in the same manner and it works fine.

Comment: You have an off by one error in your loop, the condition should be `i < a`, or more simply `while L:`. The more canonical form for an index would be `for i in range(a):` vs. a while loop.

Comment: Edited! `selectionSort()` has the argument `L`, but I managed to omit it when copying my code to this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping *once too many*:

```
i = 0
a = len(L)
while i <= a:
    #
    i += 1
```

Here `i` goes from `0` through to `len(a)` *inclusive*, so you loop `len(a) + 1` times. But there are only `len(a)` items in the list.

Your options are to pick one of the following

- start `i` at 1, not at 0
- stop at `i < a` (dropping the `=`) to not include `len(a)`
- Use a `for i in range(len(a))` loop; this produces values from 0 through to `len(a) - 1`.
- Simply test if `L` is empty with

  ```
  while L:
  ```

  and remove `a` and `i` from your code altogether.

The latter option leads to less code and is clearer:

```
def selectionSort(L):
    S = []
    while L:
        pick = min(L)
        S.append(pick) 
        L.remove(pick)
    return S #Return the sorted list
```

Note that I store the result of `min(L)` first to avoid scanning the list twice.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't thought of using `while L` instead of running the loop from a count. I agree, it is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should already be fixed by @AChampion's comment, I just want to add some clarifications about what you're trying to do. The following code should work for you, but it still has some other issues:

```
def selectionSort(L):
    S = []
    i = 0
    a = len(L)
    while i < a:  # Or even better: for i in range(len(L)) and without i += 1
        S.append(min(L)) #Find min(L) and add it to set S
        L.remove(min(L)) #Remove that same element min(L) from L
        i += 1
    return S
```

But, look at the following outputs:

```
>>> my_list = [3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4]
>>> selectionSort(my_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9]
>>>
>>> my_list
[]
```

You see, the input `my_list` is empty now, because it is altered inside your function. To fix this issue, you can do: (because you may still need to use your original list)

```
def my_sort(my_list):
    temp = my_list[:]
    sorted_list = []
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        sorted_list.append(min(temp))
        temp.remove(min(temp))
    return sorted_list
```

Now, inside our function, we use a copy of our original list `temp = my_list[:]`, this is equivalent to `temp = copy.copy(my_list)`:

```
>>> import copy
>>> 
>>> my_list = [3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4]
>>> id(my_list)
36716416
>>> l1 = my_list
>>> id(l1)
36716416  # In this case the id of l1 is the same as my_list's id!
>>> l2 = my_list[:]
>>> id(l2)
36738832  # This is NOT the same as my_list's id
>>> l3 = copy.copy(my_list)
>>> id(l3)
36766424  # This is NOT the same as my_list's id
```

**Output of the new function:**

```
>>> my_list = [3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4]
>>> my_sort(my_list)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9]
>>>
>>> my_list
[3, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 4, 7, 4]  # Our original list is still alive!
```

**You may need:**

As per your goal (implementing your own function for learning purpose), you may also need to use your own `min` function instead of the built-in one, the following is an example that you can try:

```
def my_min(my_list):
    min = my_list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(my_list)):
        if min > my_list[i]:
            min = my_list[i]
    return min
```

**Output:**

```
>>> l1 = [3, 7, 2, 5]
>>> my_min(l1)
2
```

Comment: Note `selectionSort()` is returning the sorted list `my_list = selectionSort(my_list)` would work without the copying.

Comment: @AChampion, I did not say that it would not work. I just want to mention that the OP may need to use the original list after `selectionSort` is called, which is not possible without copying!

Comment: Understood. You could also make it part of the contract and make it a choice of the caller, e.g. `my_list = selectionSort(my_list)` if it can be disposed or `new_list = selectionSort(my_list[:])` if you need to keep it around.